# Searching Notebooks for String Patterns using Workbench v2

Tags: front-end, pattern-matching, notebooks, workbench, searching

The [Workbench webpage](http://www.wolfram.com/products/workbench/newin.html) describing new features in version 2 lists the ability to "Search notebook documents with the Mathematica pattern search utility" under the heading **Mathematica Front End Integration**.

Does this feature in fact allow the user to search a Mathematica notebook document directly (i.e. interactively from within the front-end) for string pattern expressions, and if so, can anyone provide instructions on how to use this feature?

The `NotebookFind` command does not appear to support searching for string pattern expressions which raises the question of whether or not Workbench is using an undocumented Mathematica command and/or option to search for the pattern.

Comment: Nice question. You don't give up, hehe... By the way, you decided not to hand the bounty on the pattern highlighting question in the end?

Comment: I think this refers to the ability of the WB search/Mathematica search command to search for patterns like `Plus[x_Integer,Times[_,_]]` and come up with matches like `1+calcEccentricityEarthOrbit[t]*Cos[calcSunTrueAnomaly[t] \[Degree]]`. It doesn't seem to do string patterns, but for that purpose the WB has a regular expression matcher built-in.

Comment: @Rojo:  I tried to award the bounty to your answer yesterday evening on the earlier question only to discover a time limit that appears to have expired for doing so.  If a moderator can directly assign you the 50 points given the circumstances here (i.e. my lack of familiarity with how bounties can be awarded and the fact that this was the first bounty I had placed on any question) I would appreciate their efforts.

Comment: @SjoerdC.deVries:  Is it really true that the "Mathematica search command" (the same one accessible using Ctrl-F in the front-end) can search for expression patterns like the one you mention?  I cannot replicate your example using either the built-in search & replace (Ctrl-F) or using the `NotebookFind` command.  Others have suggested that one needs to search the string representation of the notebook in order to search for patterns but this is not an ideal solution for my intended application.

Comment: @StackExchanger You were talking about the workbench, which is completely different from the FrontEnd.

Comment: @SjoerdC.deVries:  Yes, in the OP I was asking about how searching for string/expression patterns in notebooks (an advertised feature for Workbench v2) can be initiated from Workbench.  OTOH, your comment appears to suggest that there is a "Mathematica search command" that can use expression patterns for the purpose of search and replacement.  What exactly are you referring to here, since neither the Cntl-F search&replace dialog nor the `NotebookFind` appear to support patterns when searching for strings?

Comment: With the phrase "WB search/Mathematica search" I intended to indicate the **Workbench** Search menu. It has a tab called "Mathematica search".

Comment: @SjoerdC.deVries:  Thanks for the clarification.  I created a simple test project in Workbench with a notebook file containing the string "Test."  I tried searching for "Test" and selected the checkbox "Include Notebooks" but get nothing in the Search results status window.  Selecting "Enclosing Project" or creating a "Working Set" doesn't return any results either, and sometimes these options are for some unknown reason unavailable (i.e. greyed out) for selection.  Searching .m files works fine though.  Very frustrating.

Comment: Please carefully re-read my first comment in the top of this thread, especially the last sentence. The regular expression matcher I was referring to there can be found in the *first* tab of the search box.

Comment: @SjoerdC.deVries  Thank you for your helpful pointers.  I have now managed to match pattern expressions in notebook files from Workbench 2 by searching for *cell expression* patterns involving boxes, rowboxes, etc.  Apparently Workbench is just searching the string representation of the notebook, which I could presumably do without leaving the front-end by reading in the notebook with `GetNotebook`.

Comment: @SjoerdC.deVries:  You've provided enough information in the comments above to answer the original question.  If you want to copy them into an answer and  post it below I will then accept it -- otherwise I will answer my own question by referring back to your comments.

Comment: @StackExchanger Done

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think this refers to the ability of the WB search/Mathematica search command to search for patterns like `Plus[x_Integer,Times[_,_]]` and come up with matches like `1+calcEccentricityEarthOrbit[t]*Cos[calcSunTrueAnomaly[t] \[Degree]]`.  You'll find it in the Workbench Search menu. It has a tab called "Mathematica search".

It doesn't seem to do string patterns, but for that purpose the WB has a regular expression matcher built-in.  This can be found in the first tab of the search box.